# Where can I get list of default images for Liferay <liferay-ui:icon> tag?

Tags: liferay-7

Can someone tell me where can I find a list of default images that I could use in image attribute?

```
 <liferay-ui:icon-menu>  
                    <liferay-ui:icon image="add" />                         
</liferay-ui:icon-menu>
```

This above one is working. But for example : 'list' is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the list
[liferay theme github](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-frontend-theme/tree/master/frontend-theme-unstyled/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/_unstyled/images/common)